# How to add a background just to a buttons value?

Tags: html, css

So basically, I have a form submit button:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Click to Search">
```

I would like to ONLY style the value, 'Click to Search'.

Currently, the button has a background color, although I would like to assign an individual background to just the value.

Is this possible without changing the structure of my HTML?

Comment: or ... `<button><span>click to search</span></button>`

Comment: As my question states... "without changing the structure of my HTML".

Comment: Yeah I got that; thats why I didn't post an answer. You havent supported why you dont want to change your html; I'm just trying to remind you how simple the alternative is.

Comment: Sorry, should have stated that. Very long story, but it is dynamically created from my Wordpress theme and it would have been a mission and a half to change around the HTML structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's always the value, how about using [Attribute Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)?

```
input[type=submit][value='Click to Search'] {
    background-color: red;
}
```

That will style only `<input>`s whose `type` attribute's value is `submit` and `value` is `Click to Search`. See a [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Rpzj5/1).

Comment: Perfect! Never knew you could do that. Thanks for the useful info :)